JProfiler doesn't profile JavaFX embedded in Swing app
I profiled a Swing desktop app successfully for years now using the cpu recording.
When I added a JavaFX view like follows:
var fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
this.add(fxPanel);
Platform.runLater(() -> {
   var root = new BorderPane();
   Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.WHITE);
   fxPanel.setScene(scene);
});

and try to profile the gui I create inside the BorderPane called root, nothing related to JavaFX is showing up in the call tree.
There is a user action that adds many JavaFX nodes and even takes over a second to complete on the JavaFX Application Thread, but still there is nothing in the JProfiler call tree. How can I profile the JavaFX gui creation call tree?
I'm starting JProfiler 13.0.7 from IntelliJ on a macOS Sonoma 14.5.

I'm guessing what the cause may be. Modern JavaFX versions (11+) are built to work as Java modules with access restrictions enforced by the Java module system. It could be that JProfiler needs to be configured to access the JavaFX Java modules. I recommend you contact the JProfiler software vendor directly for support.  I advise editing the question to include info on the JavaFX version and additional information on how you built and configured your software so that your issue can be replicated using only the info in the question.

”There is a user action that adds many JavaFX nodes and even takes over a second to complete on the JavaFX Application Thread” -> ask another question with a [mcve] and somebody can help optimize that.

As for the above comments: Neither Java modules (AWT/Swing implemention is also in a Java module)  not the availability of source code impact what is shown in the call tree view. See my answer below for more details.


nothing related to JavaFX is showing up in the call tree.

What shows up in the call tree is determined by the call tree filters in JProfiler. By default, a new session has a list of "compact" filters:

which means that only the first call into such classes from profiled classes will be shown, but the internal call structure will not.
All classes that are not included by these filters will be profiled.
It is recommended to delete this default and add your own top-level packages as "profiler" filters. This will be done automatically if you use an IDE integration. With "profiled" filters, the dialog looks like this:

In your case, start profiling from IntelliJ and edit the "call tree filters" from the "Session startup dialog":

There you can check if the package that contains your JavaFX application is included in the call tree filters.
